# Archieved app get (1) in version number?

Tags: ios, xcode

I just archieved my first app, but in the version number it get (1) after, even though the version number is changed every time I archieve? Is it the build number? Should I leave that blank?

Comment: What do you have in Target->General->Identity section->Version field?

Comment: How did you changed the version number, are you using any script ? Can you share a screenshot of the settings that you have changed and the result you are getting ?

Comment: Version field says: 1.0.0, and in archeived it says 1.0.0 (1). I just change the version number manually.

Comment: Is there a key `CFBundleVersion` in Info.plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1 in parentheses is the build number

Comment: Oh, will that be visible in the App Store version number? I see it is in TestFlight.

Comment: I don't think it's visible anywhere in the store, just the Version

Comment: Oh okay, in TestFlight it just shows like 1.0.0 (1) at version number.